# How can I sort strings alphabetically from structs in a binary file?

Tags: c, file, sorting, struct

I have some structs written into a binary file. Let's say those structs only contain `char name[20]` as member.
I'm able to access every single line of the binary file through **fseek()** and read it through **fread()**, but now I need a function that sorts alphabetically those names of the single structs.

I think the main problem is to put all of those single strings in an array of char, but how can I do it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[20];
} user; //struct user

int main() {

    user list;

    int read = 1;

    FILE *input = NULL;

    if( (input = fopen("user.dat", "rb") ) == NULL) {
        printf("Error in opening.");
    }
    else {

        while( read != 0)
        {
            read = fread(&list, sizeof(user), 1, input);

            if ( read > 0) {
                static int id = 1;
                printf("\nUSER n.%d ------> %s", id, list.name);
                id++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a standard `qsort` function. It will require some customization by writing a comparison function, but will handle the rest.

Comment: 20 characters is a very short name. Why not something longer like 255?

Comment: If you [cannot hold all the names in memory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) try merge sort with temporary files.

Comment: @pmg The problem is not if I can hold or not hold all the names in memory, but how can I "transfer" all my names from the binary file in an array of strings, in order to use the `qsort` function on it.

@tadman I don't know if you're joking or not but anyways, never seen a name of 255 characters.

Comment: start with maybe 1000 names: `user *listdata = malloc(1000 * sizeof *listdata);`, read into that and adjust size as needed. Finally `qsort()`, output, and `free(listdata);`

Comment: let's say I just have 5 users. so the call should be `malloc(5 * sizeof *listdata);`. After that, can you please elaborate the "read into that" thing? Like how I'm supposed to kinda "copy" the names in `*listdata` so I can use `qsort()` on `*listdata`?

Comment: In your code your read 1 name into list (`read = fread(&list, sizeof(user), 1, input);`). To read 5 names into listdata (after success malloc) use `read = fread(listdata, sizeof *listdata, 5, input);`. You can then access each name individually (`listdata[0]` ... `listdata[4]`) or send the whole thing to `qsort()`

Comment: Thank you. That worked. But imagine I also have a member "char surname[20]" in that struct. How can I sort them surnames alphabetically? As for the names, I use `qsort(listadata, 5, sizeof(user), cmpfunc);` and print the whole listdata array, but it doesn't seem to work for the surnames. (n.b. `cmpfunc` compares two `char*`.